# Customise the aggregate function inside dcast based on the max value of a column in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, customization, aggregate-functions, dcast

I've got a data.table that i'd like to dcast based on three columns (V1, V2, V3). there are, however, some duplicates in V3 and I need an aggregate function that looks at a fourth column V4 and decides for the value of V3 based on maximum value of V4. I'd like to do this without having to aggregate DT separately prior to dcasting. can this aggregation be done in aggregate function of dcast or do I need to aggregate the table separately first?

Here is my data.table DT:

```
> DT <- data.table(V1 = c('a','a','a','b','b','c')
                 , V2 = c(1,2,1,1,2,1)
                 , V3 = c('st', 'cc', 'B', 'st','st','cc')
                 , V4 = c(0,0,1,0,1,1))
> DT
   V1 V2 V3 V4
1:  a  1 st  0
2:  a  2 cc  0
3:  a  1  B  1 ## --> i want this row to be picked in dcast when V1 = a and V2 = 1 because V4 is largest
4:  b  1 st  0
5:  b  2 st  1
6:  c  1 cc  1
```

and the dcast function could look something like this:

```
> dcast(DT
          , V1 ~ V2
          , value.var = "V3"
         #, fun.aggregate = V3[max.which(V4)] ## ?!?!?!??!
        )
```

My desired output is:

```
> desired
   V1  1    2
1:  a  B   cc  
2:  b st   st
3:  c cc <NA>
```

Please note that aggregating DT before dcasting to get rid of the duplicates will solve the issue. I'm just wondering if dcasting can be done with the duplicates.

Comment: do you want to solve this using `data.table::dcast` only? Or you are open to other options?

Comment: I'm open to other options, as long as the solution is as fast as it can be (dealing with a large data set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option where you take the relevent subset before `dcast`ing:

```
DT[order(V4, decreasing = TRUE)
   ][, dcast(unique(.SD, by = c("V1", "V2")), V1 ~ V2, value.var = "V3")] 

#    V1  1    2
# 1:  a  B   cc
# 2:  b st   st
# 3:  c cc <NA>
```

Alternatively order and use a custom function in `dcast()`:

```
dcast(
  DT[order(V4, decreasing = TRUE)], 
  V1 ~ V2, 
  value.var = "V3", 
  fun.aggregate = function(x) x[1]
)
```

Comment: I see. I guess ordering would be faster than aggregating, so partially solves my problem. This is probably as good as it gets if I wanted to use dcast, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr`/`tidyr` option would be to `group_by` `V1` and `V2` select the maximum value in each group and then `spread` to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DT %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  slice(which.max(V4)) %>%
  select(-V4) %>%
  spread(V2, V3)


#   V1    `1`   `2`  
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1   a     B     cc   
#2   b     st    st   
#3   c     cc    NA
```

Comment: ah, interesting. I wonder if this would be any faster than dcast.

Comment: I am not sure either, you can test it on your dataset and check.

Comment: dcast with ordering seems faster.